# Bind IsEnable property of button located inside data grid to variable

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I want to bind IsEnable property of button to variable. Button is added inside data grid. Data Grid is located inside user control.
Below code is not working.

```
 <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Start"  >
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Button x:Name="Start_Button"
                                 DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}},Path=DataContext}" 
                                  IsEnabled="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}},Path=IsStartButtonEnable}"
                            Command="{Binding StartCommand}">START
                        </Button>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Model contains-(ServerModel.cs)

```
        private bool _isStartButtonEnable = false;

    public bool IsStartButtonEnable
    {
        get
        {
            return _isStartButtonEnable;
        }
        set
        {
            _isStartButtonEnable = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged("IsStartButtonEnable");
        }
    }
```

View Model(ServerViewModel.cs) Contains -

```
  public static ObservableCollection<ServerModel> DataGridServerList { get; set; }
```

UserControl (ServerUserControl.cs) contains -

```
  this.DataContext = new ServerViewModel();
```

Requirements - UserControl contains 3 buttons-Create, Start and Stop. User clicks on Create Button. If Create commnd gets success, then Start button gets enabled.Then user will click on Start button. If start commnd gets executed successfully, then Stop button gets enabled and so on.

Comment: What type of an ICommand are you using? Is it a RelayCommand? If it is, you can use the CanExecute predicate of the command to enable or disable the button. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh727783%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Yes, I am using RelayCommand. UserControl contains 3 buttons-Create, Start and Stop. User clicks on Create Button. If Create commnd gets success, then Start button gets enabled.Then user will click on Start button. If start commnd gets executed successfully, then Stop button gets enabled and so on.

Comment: @user660232 If your flag is in the ViewModel my small modification should do the job.Of course if the DataContext of your UserControl is the ViewModel.

Comment: Right...But flag is inside Model and not ViewModel

Comment: @user660232 I've just updated my answer. Such a scenario works for me. You could try it. I am not sure why you have to set that flag in the Model but .. that's a way to get to it.

Comment: Buttons are located inside data grid. Based on which button user clicks, individual buttons within data grid gets enabled or disabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Start"  >
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Button x:Name="Start_Button"
                             IsEnabled="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}},Path=DataContext.IsStartButtonEnable}"
                        Command="{Binding StartCommand}">START
                    </Button>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

I am using the DataContext of the UserControl directly and not that of the DataGrid.
In your case, indeed, the DataContext of the Button will be set to each item in the DataGrid. In order to access the property on your UserControl you need this change. Further more, you don't need to set the DataContext again so i removed that line.

You have two possibilities in my opinion. Either set the flag in the ViewModel and will be accessible by all Buttons through the Relative Source syntax or if you have it in the Model, you will have a flag for each row in the DataGrid.  In either case you have the response:

1. If it is in the Model, set the DataGrid ItemsSource to your ObservableCollection and use

   ```
   IsEnabled = {Binding IsStartButtonEnable }
   ```

2.If it is in the ViewModel, use

```
    IsEnabled="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}},Path=DataContext.IsStartButtonEnable}"
```

I don't see other option but if you want it available for all Buttons in the DataGrid you have to set it in the ViewModel.

Comment: If I set IsEnabled as specified abopve, then I need to remove DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}},Path=DataContext}" . Thne it works. But then below statement gets failed to execute- Command="{Binding StartCommand}"

Comment: @user660232 The command is located in the ViewModel and not in the Model, so use the RelativeSource syntax for the Command in order to go back the UserControls's DataContext. Something like : Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}, Path=DataContext.StartCommand}">

Comment: I have used following  code. Its not working.  <Button 
                                 IsEnabled="{Binding Path=IsCreateButtonEnable}"
                                            Command="{Binding Path=CreateMyCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"
                                >CREATE
                                        </Button>

Comment: StartCommand is in the ViewModel which is set as DataContext for the UserControl?

Comment: Working Solution -   <Button 
                                 IsEnabled="{Binding Path=IsCreateButtonEnable}"
                                            Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.CreateMyCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"
                                >CREATE
                                        </Button>